# how do we can set the font height in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, fonts, elementor

My new website uses a UI designed in Photoshop. **Astra Theme** with **elementor** plugin is used in the new WordPress update (6.3.2). The same font suggested by WordPress is used in Photoshop. But the font is not showing like in photoshop. The preview image shown in Photoshop and shown in WordPress is attached. **Montserrat font used**. I thought that the correct font style was not displayed because it was used directly, so I looked with the custom font plugin. But no change was seen. Hope those who know will help.

[[image: font shows in photoshop1]

[image: Font shows in WordPress]

Answer (score 0):

You can see my recommendations:

1. Use popular fonts from google font: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat
2. Have you reviewed the PSD file design to see if the Montserrat font is included? If it is showing on your computer find the ttf file and convert it to web font and find a way to add it.
3. From the picture you provided. I think it has the correct Montserrat font but lacks the dark and light style versions... and you can look into the details at google fonts Montserrat like point 1 I mentioned.

Hope the above 3 things will be useful to you

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work